# Marshalling an unsigned short to SafeHandle

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, interop, marshalling

I'm communicating with a third party library where I need to acquire and the release an unmanaged resource. After some reading I came to the conclusion that best and 'correct' way to  manage the resource reference was in either a `SafeHandle` or `CriticalHandle` object.

My problem arises because the handles returned by the third party library are unsigned short numeric values as opposed to pointers. If I specify the `MarshalAsAttribute` on the returned handle I get a `MarshalDirectiveException` (CriticalHandles must not have a MarshalAs attribute set and cannot be used in arrays).

Here are the things that I've considered:

- Marshal the handles in their numeric format and wrap them in a `CriticalHandle` via the `Criticalhandle.SetHandle` Method. This allows the potential to leak a handle if an exception is raised between obtaining the reference and encapsulating it.
- Marshal and store the handles in their numeric format. Have the containing type implement `CriticalFinalizerObject`. This allows the potential to leak a handle if an exception is raised between obtaining the reference and encapsulating it.
- Marshal the handles into a `SafeHandle` as an `IntPtr` (letting the most significant 2 bytes fill with quasi-garbage). Cast the `DangerousGetHandle` back down to a short (discarding the most significant 2 bytes of garbage) every time I need to invoke a native method with the `SafeHandle`. This will prevent the any potential leaks of the handle but is very cumbersome and has the appearance of using brute force to make the wrong solution work.

How should I handle these 'handles'?

Comment: You can make SafeHandle work if your native code is 32-bits.  A short argument always gets promoted to int in a C or C++ function call.  The IntPtr won't confuse it.

Comment: This reassures me a bit but that leave me wondering why extra data is sometimes filled into the most significant 2 bytes in the returned value. IE: Sometimes the upper 2 bytes contain the bit pattern of all 0's and other times contain the bit pattern of 0x0091. While I know the scenarios that lead to both circumstances I have no clue what the extra bits represent. Perhaps this is something specific to my library that I should investigate. Thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant This worked very nicely for me. May you post this as an answer so that I may accept it?

Comment: @HansPassant I have posted your comment as an answer (and marked it as the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HansPassant mentioned in a comment to my question:

> You can make SafeHandle work if your native code is 32-bits. A short
>   argument always gets promoted to int in a C or C++ function call. The
>   IntPtr won't confuse it. – Hans Passant Jul 4 at 15:10

It is therefore possible to marshal a C/C++ unsigned short directly into a derivative of `SafeHandle`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct thing to do here is implement your own wrapper similar to `SafeHandle` (and derived from `CriticalFinalizerObject`. Then wrap the call to your P/Invoke method that creates the handle in a [constrained execution region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228973.aspx) to ensure the managed handle wrapper is properly initialized.

**NOTE: I haven't had to use a CER before, so without verification I can only hope this code provides you with a starting point.**

```
[DllImport("blah.dll")]
private static extern ushort CreateMySpecialHandle();

public static SafeSpecial Handle Foo()
{
    SafeSpecialHandle safeHandle = new SafeSpecialHandle();
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
    try
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        ushort rawHandle = CreateMySpecialHandle();
        safeHandle.SetHandle(rawHandle);
    }

    if (safeHandle.IsInvalid)
    {
        // throw exception here, or other error handling
    }

    return safeHandle;
}
```

Comment: I read this article but was left uncertain as to what qualified as an 'out-of-band' exception. Without this I'm unable to determine if there are scenarios where `CreateMySpecialhandle()` will execute and obtain a handle but not have it saved inside the `SafeHandle`.

Comment: This example seems to be reinforced by the nearly identical snippet with additional information found in the MSDN [`RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.prepareconstrainedregions.aspx) method documentation.